# Is there a code formatter tool for Haxe code?

Tags: haxe

Is there a Haxe code formatter, to beautify code?

Alternatively, if there is one that is made for other languages, but works well enough, it can also be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's now a dedicated code formatter for Haxe called [haxe-formatter](https://github.com/HaxeCheckstyle/haxe-formatter). Compared to astyle, it actually properly understands all Haxe-specific constructs, including the latest Haxe 4 syntax and conditional compilation. You can install it from Haxelib and reformat your code from the command line:

```
haxelib install formatter
haxelib run formatter -s <source-directory>
```

It's also integrated into the Haxe extension for VSCode [out of the box](https://github.com/vshaxe/vshaxe/wiki/Formatting):

[image]

A very convenient way to use it is to enable "format on save" and "format on paste" in your settings, so your code is always formatted correctly:

```
"[haxe]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true
}
```

But of course, you can also invoke the `Format Document` command manually (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

Answer (score 3):

I found `astyle`.

with a c# mode, it works well for haxe as well.

#### Command line example:

`astyle --mode=cs -f -U -Y -o -xe -xg -xL -S -t -xj -xt1 -xW -z2 *.hx`

note: `-p` messes up `regex literal`, and macros (`@:annotation`)

### Setting up formatting in `vscode` editor:

install extension: `Astyle`.
edit `settings.json` (general vscode User prefs)

```
"astyle.haxe.enable": true,
"astyle.cmd_options": [ "--mode=cs", "-f", "-U", "-Y", "-o", "-xe", "-xg", "-xL", "-S", "-t", "-xj", "-xt1", "-xW", "-z2" ],
```

now, edit the extension file to include 'haxe'.
open file:
`~/.vscode-insiders/extensions/chiehyu.vscode-astyle-0.4.0`

line 111 lists languages, add 'haxe', so it reads:
`["c", "cpp", "objective-c", "csharp", "java", "haxe"]`

Next: disable the extension, restart, enable it again.
open a file from one of the languages above, and format it `(ctrl shift I)`.

This should now register for haxe files as well.

Formatting should now work for `*.hx` files using the same shortcut.